# Matching two divs height on resize in React

Tags: reactjs

I have this

```
const divRef = createRef()
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 1, height: 2 })

const useRefDimensions = (ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const { current } = ref
      const boundingRect = current.getBoundingClientRect()
      const { width, height } = boundingRect
      setDimensions({ width: Math.round(width), height: Math.round(height) })
    }     
  }, [ref])
  return dimensions
}
useRefDimensions(divRef)
```

On the render...

```
<Row>
  <Col md={12} lg={7}>
    <Card bg="dark" ref={divRef}>
      Some image or video here    
    </Card>
  </Col>
  <Col md={12} lg={5}>
    <PerfectScrollbar style={{height: dimensions.height}} >
      <Card bg="dark">
        Some stuff in here
      </Card>
    </PerfectScrollbar>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

I can make it work (sort of) but only if I use the `ref` dependency. Problem is, I get an error and what it looks like an infinite loop

> index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

EDIT - The entire component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import { Card, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import PerfectScrollbar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar'
import succession from '../../assets/images/succession/succession.jpeg'
import successiontrailerposter from '../../assets/images/succession/succesion trailer.jpg'
import successiontrailer from '../../assets/images/succession/successionTrailer.mp4'
import {ReactVideo} from 'reactjs-media'

const metadata = [
  {
    title: "Succession",
    source: "HBO",
    type: "Original",
    mediatype: "TV Series",
    rating: "TV-MA",
    seasons: 3,
    episodes: 30,
    poster: succession,
    trailerposter: successiontrailerposter,
    trailer: successiontrailer,
    summary: "When Logan Roy (Brian Cox) announces his plans to step back from running the family's multi-national entertainment company, a feud over who will be have control causes tension among his four children.",
    info: [
      {
        releasedate: "June 3, 2018",
        availabilitydate: "May 27, 2020",
        runtime: "56 - 70 minutes",
        genres:[ "Drama", "Comedy-Drama", "Black-Comedy" ],
        tags: ["Patriarchy", "finance", "based on true story" ],
        regions: ["North America", "Latin America"],
        language: "English",
        awards: ["Golden Globe: Best TV Series"],
        prod_budget: "$50,000,000",
        marketing_budget: "$3,000,000",
      }
    ]

  }
]

const Home = () => {
    const divRef = useRef()
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 1, height: 2 })
    
      useEffect((ref) => {
        if (ref.current) {
          const { current } = ref
          const boundingRect = current.getBoundingClientRect()
          const { width, height } = boundingRect
          setDimensions({ width: Math.round(width), height: Math.round(height) + 35 })
        }     
      return dimensions
      }, [dimensions])

  return (
    <div className="container-fluid pt-3 px-5">
      {metadata.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div key={index}>
            <div className="d-flex align-items-end justify-content-between pb-4">
              <h1 className="item-title m-0 text-primary text-bold">{item.title}</h1>
              <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-end justify-content-end">
                <p className="m-0">{item.source} {item.type} | {item.mediatype} | {item.rating}</p>
                <p className="m-0">Seasons: {item.seasons} ({item.episodes} episodes)</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <Row>
              <Col xs={12} md={3} lg={2}>
                <Card bg="dark">
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.poster} />
                </Card>
              </Col>
              <Col xs={12} md={9} lg={10}>
                <Row className="media-info">
                  <Col 
                    md={12} 
                    lg={7} 
                    className="media-container" >
                    <Card bg="dark" ref={divRef}>
                      <ReactVideo 
                        src={item.trailer} 
                        poster={item.trailerposter} 
                        className="video-player"/>      
                    </Card>
                  </Col>
                  <Col 
                    md={12} 
                    lg={5} 
                    className="metadata-container" >
                    <PerfectScrollbar style={{ height: dimensions.height }}>
                      <Card bg="dark">
                        <Card.Body>
                          <div className="mb-3">
                            <h4 className="card-h4">Series Summary</h4>
                            <p className="card-p">{item.summary}</p>
                          </div>
                          <div>
                            <h4 className="card-h4">Series Metadata</h4>
                            <ul className="card-ul">
                              <li>
                                <label>Release Date: </label>
                                <span>{item.info[0].releasedate}</span>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>HBO Max First Availability Date: </label>
                                <span>{item.info[0].availabilitydate}</span> 
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>Runtime: </label>
                                <span>{item.info[0].runtime}</span> 
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>Genre(s): </label>
                                { item.info[0].genres.map((genre, index) => {
                                  return (
                                    <span key={`genre_${index}`}>
                                      { (index ? ', ' : '') + genre }
                                    </span>                          
                                  )
                                })} 
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>Plot Tag(s): </label>                          
                                { item.info[0].tags.map((tag, index) => {
                                  return (
                                    <span key={`tag_${index}`}>
                                      { (index ? ', ' : '') + tag }
                                    </span>                          
                                  )
                                })} 
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>Region Availability: </label>
                                { item.info[0].regions.map((region, index) => {
                                  return (
                                    <span key={`region_${index}`}>
                                      { (index ? ', ' : '') + region }
                                    </span>                          
                                  )
                                })}
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>Original Language: </label>
                                <span>{item.info[0].language}</span>
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>Awards: </label>
                                { item.info[0].awards.map((award, index) => {
                                  return (
                                    <span key={`award_${index}`}>
                                      { (index ? ', ' : '') + award }
                                    </span>                          
                                  )
                                })}
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>Production Budget: </label>
                                <span>{item.info[0].prod_budget}</span> 
                              </li>
                              <li>
                                <label>Marketing Budget: </label>
                                <span>{item.info[0].marketing_budget} </span>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </Card.Body>
                      </Card>
                    </PerfectScrollbar>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Col>
              
            </Row>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: Matching two divs heights! One div has a dynamic height and it's referenced by a ref. The other div's style: {{height: the ref's height}}. It's all in the code

Comment: Why is your custom hook inline? I would remove that as it's not really reusable the way it is.

Comment: What do you mean by "reusable"? This is pretty much the only place I'm using it in.

Comment: Show your full component if you want more help.

Comment: ok. Stand by for the full component

Comment: @morganney Question edited with the entire component. I don't see how the rest will help. It just added bloat to the question. But I've been wrong before.

Comment: You're referencing `ref` not `divRef` inside of your `useEffect` still. You also don't need to `return dimensions` any more.

Comment: Yeah, this is why showing code is important. I didn't realize that until after you posted code

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a new ref every time `setDimensions` is called. Change `createRef` to `useRef`. I'd also remove the `useRefDimensions` function and just call `useEffect` directly.

```js
const divRef = useRef(null)
const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 1, height: 2 })

useEffect(() => {
  if (divRef.current) {
    const { current } = divRef
    const boundingRect = current.getBoundingClientRect()
    const { width, height } = boundingRect
    setDimensions({ width: Math.round(width), height: Math.round(height) })
  }     
}, [divRef])
```